# Is there good FAT driver for FUSE? (Lightweight, not mountlo)

Tags: linux, filesystems, fat32, fuse

FUSE [filesystem list](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=NonNativeFileSystems) show some FuseFat and FatFuse. Both are old, FatFuse is read-only , FuseFat is non-buildable and probably depends on glib.

Now I'm using [mountlo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse/files/mountlo/) for the task (mounting USB drives in generic way without root access or suid things (except of fusermount itself)), but it looks too big for such task.

Using FUSE to mount external storage devices is good both for security and for flexibility reason: the kernel sees only block reads and writes while actual code that deals with filesystem details runs with user privileges, allowing user to use custom filesystems and preventing from kernel filesystem exploits.

Is there good vfat FUSE driver?

Comment: What's wrong with the kernel driver?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, Kernel (and consequently mountlo) driver works OK. But using kernel driver is 1. giving user too much control over filesystems (user may deliberately put some malformed "specially crafted" filesystem), 2. Limiting filesystem types or partition table styles he can use. FUSE is good answer for both. And mountlo (start UML kernel and use "in-kernel" filesystem running in user-space) is solution with overhead (memory usage, for example).

Comment: One more thing: with FUSE I always forcibly unmount my drive in correct way (including when using mountlo).

Comment: see also [fusefat in debian](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/fusefat) and ["fuse fat" on github](https://github.com/search?q=fuse+fat). all of them look unpopular, so probably are lacking features compared to the `vfat` kernel driver

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which "FuseFat" you tried, but Debian & Ubuntu do have `fusefat` packages available in their repositories, so it *is* buildable somehow (maybe they have some useful patches?).  And yes, it needs GLib, but I'm not sure why that would be a problem?

Comment: However, it gives big warnings that `rw` is experimental .